# How can i perform the arithmetic operation in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Now I want to perform the arithmetic operation through query.
So, I need my output like (points[1]+points[2]+points[4]-points[3] = result). 
Example:
50+50+50-150 = 0 Points.

So how is this possible via **sql** query.

```
+-------------+-----+
| points_type | sum |
+-------------+-----+
|           1 |  50 |
|           2 |  50 |
|           3 | 150 |
|           4 |  50 |
+-------------+-----+
```

Comment: What does this HTML table have to do with SQL?  What is your table design?

Comment: How does the documentation say to do it?   Do you get an error when you try it?

Comment: "So how is this possible via sql query. "  `SELECT 0+50+50-150`

Comment: Please post the table structure with table name, column name etc. . Performing sql on html is not the right way of asking.

Comment: Will this query only ever run against a table containing 4 rows with those specific IDs? If not, what's the *general* rule to apply here?

Comment: How do you know which one to subtract?

Comment: those are fixed we have to subtract 3 from the sum of 1,2 and 4

Answer (score 2):

You could do

`SELECT SUM(sum) - 2 * (SELECT sum from TableName WHERE points_type = 3) FROM TableName`

Where `TableName` is the name of your table

Comment: That would result in `300`, not `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified how you know which one(s) to subtract, so to keep it a bit general, you can use the following:

```
Select  Sum(Case When Points_Type In (3) Then -Sum Else Sum End)
From    YourTable
```

If you had others you wanted to subtract (for example, if you wanted to also subtract `5`), you can just add it to the `IN` clause:

```
Select  Sum(Case When Points_Type In (3, 5) Then -Sum Else Sum End)
From    YourTable
```